# Why is my 2 function not get called in 1st and 2nd loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am working on this pyqt5 UI design and I need to loop through ids and check True/false and update the window accordingly. When I run this code and give 3 ids, it calls getsensor function and paintevent function only during the last id. Why is function getsensor and paintevent not being called during 1st 2 loop when id are id_123 and id_234.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, Qt
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QPen, QColor
import time

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,id_, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        # counter
        self.correct = 0
        self.incorrect = 0
        self.id_ = id_
        self.setStyleSheet("QLabel {font: 8pt Arial}")
        self.qLbl = QLabel("Not yet initialized")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.qLbl)
        self.qTimer = QTimer()
        self.qTimer.setInterval(1000)
        self.qTimer.singleShot(1000, self.getSensorValue)
        # self.qTimer.timeout.connect(self.getSensorValue)
        self.qTimer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.qTimer.start()
        self.color = QColor()
        self.repaint()
        self.update()

    def getSensorValue(self):

        result = (bool(random.getrandbits(1)))
        print("Result",self.id_,result)
        if result == True:
            self.correct = self.correct + 1
        else:
            self.incorrect = self.incorrect + 1
        # self.qLbl.setText("{} {}".format(id_, result))
        self.qLbl.setText(" {} {} {}".format(str(self.id_), self.correct, self.incorrect))
        # self.color = QColor("green") if result==True else QColor("red")
        if result == True:
            self.color =QColor("green")
        elif result == False:
            self.color  = QColor("red")
        else:
            self.color =QColor("black")
        self.repaint()
        self.update()
            # return result

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        print("test1",self.id_)
        if self.color.isValid():
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.color, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(self.color, Qt.SolidPattern))
            painter.drawRect(40, 40, 400, 200)
#

qApp = QApplication(sys.argv)


ids=["id_123","id_234","id_345"]
for i in ids:
    import random

    qWin = MainWindow(id_=i)
    # qWin.getSensorValue()
    time.sleep(1)
    qWin.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 1000)
    qWin.show()
sys.exit(qApp.exec_())


# run application
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007, Sorry I had to remove  1 import that was not being used. Now the code should work

Comment: Unused imports don't affect code working. I'm saying that do you really need pyqt to test the for loop at the end?

Comment: @cricket_007, ah. I am actually trying to update the data/UI in same window using those id so I thought it would be helpful to see what I was trying to do. At the moment, it doesn't update the window/enter the id loop until very end.

Comment: indent the `qWin.show()` it's currently outside the look so only gets called after the look is ran, where the last value in the list is currently in qWin

Comment: @KJTHoward, hi even with qWin.show() indented, it will still enter the loop at the last id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your qWin. The variable is being overwritten with MainWindow("id_345") instance in your FOR loop. Therefore, you only call the show() method of that instance which the only instance's GUI window that will be displayed.

Solution:

1. Put qWin.show() inside the FOR loop.
2. Create a list of qWin to store the instances.

```
qWin = []
ids=["id_123","id_234","id_345"]

for i in range(len(ids)):
    qWin.append(MainWindow(ids[i])) 
    qWin[i].getSensorValue() 
    time.sleep(1) 
    qWin[i].setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 1000) 
    qWin[i].show()
```

Comment: Hi, Solution 1 doesn't work. it still skips 1st 2 ids. However, can you elaborate what you mean in solution 2 please.

Comment: Basically the qWin variable is being overwritten with new instance.

Solution:

qWin = []
ids=["id_123","id_234","id_345"]
for i in ids:
    import random

    qWin.append(MainWindow(ids[i]))
    qWin[i].getSensorValue()
    time.sleep(1)
    qWin[i].setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 1000)
    qWin[i].show()

Comment: how can i avoid qWin from being overwritten?

Comment: Create qWin as a list and append new instances of MainWindow class into the qWin list.

Comment: ids=["id_123","id_234","id_345"]
qApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
qWin1=[]
for i in ids:
    import random


    qWin = MainWindow(id_=i)
    qWin1.append(qWin)
    # qWin.getSensorValue()
    time.sleep(1)
    qWin.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 1000)
    qWin.show()
sys.exit(qApp.exec_())

Comment: See the main answer. I have edited it with an example of the code.

Comment: This does solve the problem of not looping through 1st 2 ids. Thank you. It does open multiple windows. I will accept this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It's only using the last id because you're showing the window outside the loop

I suggest looking into a MVC or MVP Patterns where your data is stored separately from any GUI

Comment: Hi Criket, even if I have show window inside the loop, it still enters the loop at last id

Comment: Have you tried putting `qApp = QApplication(sys.argv)` inside the loop as well?

Comment: Yes, If I put that line inside the loop, code breaks with message "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

Comment: So 1) your calling `sys.exit(qApp.exec_())` without actually waiting for the close event of any window 2) if you simply printed `self.id_` inside the window class you should see every id get printed. If you created a [mcve] with a simple class and a loop, you can recreate the same problem

Comment: even when I just print self.id_ it still doesn't print it in 2 of those function. It loops throught Init function but it never enters getsensorvalue paintevent until last loop (id_345)

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your updated code with the corrected indentation that you claim doesn't work? Again, this seems to be a standard python problem and unrelated to pyqt

Comment: I have edited the code